# Disable AccountChooser for Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, openid, firebase-authentication

I'm trying the new FirebaseUI for Web (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Web). But when I tried to login with Email, it redirects me to an AccountChooser website.

Is there anyway that I can turn off that AccountChooser?

Thanks

Answer (score 27):

You can disable by adding an entry into the variable `uiConfig` in Firebase. You have to add this in the uiConfig variable:

```js
'credentialHelper': firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE
```

Here is an example of it inside `uiConfig`:

```js
var uiConfig = {
    callbacks: {
        signInSuccess: function (currentUser, credential, redirectUrl) {
            return true;
        },
        uiShown: function () {
            document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
        }
    },
    //Start it here 
    credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE,
    //End it here 
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    signInSuccessUrl: '<url-to-redirect-to-on-success>',
    signInOptions: [
        // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    // Terms of service url.
    tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>'
};

var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone isn't bringing in firebaseui (e.g. if you're using react-firebaseui), it could be helpful know that`firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE === 'none'`

This answer was provided in this SO question: [Disable account chooser FirebaseUI React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181745/disable-account-chooser-firebaseui-react)
Credit to @RafikTighilt and @JeffBergman

Answer (score 1):

I am using `/__/firebase/init.js` and no explicit initialization and getting

> firebaseui not initialized on ,'credentialHelper': firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE

Solution, change the order of the statements:

1. `var ui = new ...`
2. `var uiConfig = { ...`
3. `ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);`

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Found a fix for this here:</strike>

https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/42

Download the `firebase-ui-auth.js` file (you can copy `version 0.5` from [here](https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/live/0.5/firebase-ui-auth.js)). You need to change one character and host the file yourself instead of using the CDN.

In the file, look for: `"accountChooserEnabled",!0` and change the `!0` to `!1`.

This did the trick for me!

Comment: This is outdated now.