# Disable account chooser FirebaseUI React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm struggling with something that looks like a piece of cake, but I still can't manage to find a solution.

I'm implementing a firebase authentication process, with reactjs and [firebaseUI web react](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react). Everything is just fine, except the fact that when I try to login using email/password, it takes me to [accountchooser](https://accountchooser.com), which is a behavior I don't want.

I searched the docs, github issues etc... But All I found was adding the line below in the `uiConfig` object :

```
credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE
```

The problem is that react throws an error complaining about firebaseui not being defined, and it's pretty normal I guess because I never imported it.

I found a hint while browsing, telling to pass a `uiCallback` prop to the component, but I am not able to figure it out.

So far, here is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

const uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    signInSuccessUrl: '/signedIn',
    signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    ],
};

export default class SignInScreen extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>My App</h1>
            <p>Please sign-in:</p>
            <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

I don't even know if I am trying the right thing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message when you try and run the code with the UI call back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for those it may help, I found a solution to that problem.

1. `yarn add firebaseui`
2. `import firebaseui from 'firebaseui'`
3. set `credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE` in the uiConfig object.

I don't know if installing firebaseui over firebaseUI web react is something good, but it solved my problem.

Comment: Rafik, functionally no problem with your solution but wouldn't importing `firebaseui` into your code just for the constant unnecessarily bloat your package size? Seems overkill. Haven't found a good solution myself.

Comment: Yes it is overkill. Jeff Bergman's answer solves that problem.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks, Rafik! I've been looking for a solution to this for hours.

It turns out that `firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE` === 'none', so I'm using that instead of importing the extra firebaseui.

I don't love either solution (importing extra stuff or using the constant's underlying value), and I certainly wish they'd include that constant in react-firebaseui.

Comment: Can you add some more detail, your answer is unclear.

Comment: He means that the `firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE` constant's value is the string litteral "none". So you can simply replace the constant (that implicitly forces you to require some more stuff) by its value.

Comment: That is what I mean. Thanks again Rafik.

Comment: so instead of, firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE, just use 'none'

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me: According to the comments above, add credentialHelper beneath your signInOptions Array in uiConfig. Full code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

const uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    signInSuccessUrl: '/signedIn',
    signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    ],
    credentialHelper: 'none'
};

export default class SignInScreen extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>My App</h1>
            <p>Please sign-in:</p>
            <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, no need to import firebaseui again just for firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE ... since its value is just 'none'.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the `uiConfig` a property of the `SignInScreen class`, then referring to the callback using `this.uiConfig` when you pass it to the component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

export default class SignInScreen extends Component {

  uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    signInSuccessUrl: '/signedIn',
    signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    ],
    'credentialHelper': firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE
};

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>My App</h1>
            <p>Please sign-in:</p>
            <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={this.uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

This is based on the example provided [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react#accessing-the-firebaseui-instance)

Comment: I tried this, but how can I add the property `credentialHelper` ? There is still no effect sadly.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting when you make the changes?

Comment: I don't have any error message, it just doesn't do anything

Comment: You say you haven't imported Firebase UI, have you tried that also?

Comment: I just found a solution, I'm updating the post. Thanks :)