# Problems using email/password login from firebase in Angular website

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm an Angular newbie have inherited an Angular website which is "Not Quite Working Yet".

Part of the website requires users to login, and we have a Firebase login - the login options are Google, and mail/password (later I'm supposed to get to Apple but I need to get this part working first).

The Google logins work smoothly - click on the button and a popup allows you to select a Google account and when I return to my page it knows it is logged in. Here is the code which is creating the initial login screen:

**firebase-auth-uui.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { auth } from "firebase";
import * as firebaseui from "firebaseui";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import { UserInfo } from "../../models/user-info";
import * as Rx from "rxjs";
import AuthUI = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI;
import Config = firebaseui.auth.Config;

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseAuthUiService {

    private firebaseUi: AuthUI;

    private appleProvider: auth.OAuthProvider = new auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com');
    private uiConfig: Config = {
        signInFlow: "popup",
        signInSuccessUrl: '/login-pending',
        signInOptions: [
            auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        ],
        tosUrl: 'https://www.mycompany.com/terms-conditions/',
        // Privacy policy url/callback.
        privacyPolicyUrl: function () {
            window.location.assign('https://www.mycompany.com/privacy-policy/');
        }
    };

    constructor() {
        console.log("constructor initializing firebaseUI"); // I see this log when I start up
        this.firebaseUi = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    }

    public isUserLoggedIn() {
        console.log("hitting isUserLoggedIn"); // NEVER see this

        var s = new Rx.Subject();

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                console.log("and we ARE logged in");
                s.next(new UserInfo(user.uid, user.displayName, user.email, user.phoneNumber, user.photoURL, user.providerId));
            } else {
                console.log("we are NOT logged in");
                s.next();
            }
        });

        return s.asObservable();

    }

    public start(selector: string | Element, signInSuccessWithAuthResult, signInFailure, uiShown) {
        console.log("called firebase START with selector = " + selector); // I see this, selector is "#fui-container"
        this.uiConfig.callbacks = {
            signInSuccessWithAuthResult: signInSuccessWithAuthResult,
            signInFailure: signInFailure,
            uiShown: uiShown
        };
        this.firebaseUi.start(selector, this.uiConfig);
    }


    private signInSuccessWithAuthResult(authResult, redirectUrl): boolean {
        var user = authResult.user;
        var credential = authResult.credential;
        var isNewUser = authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;
        var providerId = authResult.additionalUserInfo.providerId;
        var operationType = authResult.operationType;
        console.log(user, credential, isNewUser, providerId, operationType); // NEVER see this
        return false;
    }

    private signInFailure(error): Promise<void> {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    private uiShown(): void {
        console.log("Hit firebase ui shown"); // NEVER see this
    }

}
```

As you can see  - there are a number of functions which I never seem to hit, even though this login seems to work - and work from *here*, since I DO see some of the logs. I found another class where this code gets called:

**login-component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseAuthUiService } from "../../services/firebase/firebase-auth-ui.service";
import { MatSnackBar } from "@angular/material";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output()
  onFinish: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();

  private readonly AUTH_CONTAINER = '#fui-container';

  progressHidden = false;
  authHidden = true;

  constructor(private authUi: FirebaseAuthUiService,  private snackbar: MatSnackBar) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authUi.start(
        this.AUTH_CONTAINER,
        this.signInSuccessWithAuthResult.bind(this),
        this.signInFailure.bind(this),
        this.uiShown.bind(this)
    );
  }

  private signInSuccessWithAuthResult(authResult, redirectUrl): boolean {
      console.log("success on login component, redirect url is: " + redirectUrl); //I see this, redirect url is always 'undefined'
      var user = authResult.user;
      var isNewUser = authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;
      console.log("Is new user = " + isNewUser);
      var providerId = authResult.additionalUserInfo.providerId;
      var needVerification = false;
      if (providerId == 'password') {
          console.log("it's an email");
          // check if it's verified
          if (user.emailVerified) {
              console.log("Mail is verified");
          } else {
              console.log("email not verified");
              needVerification = true;
          }

      } else {
          console.log("provider = " + providerId);
      }
      var operationType = authResult.operationType;

      if (needVerification) {
          console.log("Sending an email verification"); // and email verification IS sent
          user.sendEmailVerification();
          let snackbarMessage = "E-mail needs verification. A verification email has been sent to " + user.email; // I do see this for unverified email
          this.snackbar.open(snackbarMessage);
      }

      this.onFinish.emit();
      return false;
  }

  private signInFailure(error): Promise<void> {
    console.log('signInFailure', error); // never see this but it's not a worry

    this.onFinish.emit();
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  private uiShown() {
      console.log("hit ui shown"); //I DO see this
    this.progressHidden = true;
    this.authHidden = false;
  }
}
```

This code DOES manage to detect if a user signed in from an unverified email and sends them a verification link, but I have  big problem:

When I use the Google login it works and I'm logged in, when I use the email login, the first time it redirects me to a page to choose an email address (URL is https://www.accountchooser.com/redirect.html#my.website.com) and when I choose an email it just returns me to where I was without having logged me in. The second time I press my login button it takes me to a popup with the email id I chose before and allows me to enter a password - after that I am actually logged in (and I hit the code to check if the email is verified). I would obviously like this popup with the password prompt to come up right away but it doesn't.

I've been scouring Google and StackOverflow for days and tried reading the Firebase literature over and over but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

**EDITED TO REMOVE SECOND QUESTION**

**SECOND EDIT**
It turns out that the problem is caused by having "Account Chooser" active on my browser. When I disable it, everything works fine. So the question is really now - how do I automatically avoid calling AccountChooser on my website?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please limit yourself to a single question per post.

Comment: @DougStevenson removed second question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that when you want to disable the AccountChooser for your particular login instance you just add in to the firebaseui.auth.Config object this line

```
credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE
```

I found this answer here:

[Disable account chooser FirebaseUI React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181745/disable-account-chooser-firebaseui-react)

Also, it looks like this problem will go away on its own pretty soon because AccountChooser is going away [as it says here](http://www.accountchooser.net/developers)